# Example of a function which is continuous and $1$-periodic but not differentiable

Tags: real-analysis

> Give an example of a function $f:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ such that $f$ is continuous and periodic with period $1$ but not differentible

My try

Consider the function $f$ whose graph is

[image]

Actually it is a graph of $f$ in the interval $[-1,2].$ By extend this to rightside and leftside , we get $f$.

Here $f$ is continuous and periodic with period $1$, but $f$ is not differentiable at $\Bbb Z \cup \{n+\frac{1}{2}: n \in \Bbb Z\}$.

Is this correct? Also other examples are welcome !

Comment: You can just take any continuous, non-differentiable on $[0,1]$ function with $f(0)=f(1)$ and extend it periodically. There are even examples of continuous, nowhere differentiable functions with that property.

Comment: Yes it's correct... As you can see, with these example, you can build infinitely many other example based on this principle ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Yes of course you are correct, if you want to prove it formally just take the equations and do the limits. Another function which is continious, periodic and not differentiable in every point is $f(x)= |\sin(x)|$

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is correct. It is continuous in every point, not differentiable at a certain point, and 1-periodic. 
Another example would be to do the same pattern you have (spikes) but not on a 1-period, but on a 0.5-period, and on the missing part make the function be zero.

$f(x) = x$ between 0 and a forth.
$f(x) = (0.5 - x)$ between a forth and a half.
$f(x) = 0$ between a half and 1.

Then repeat the pattern.